# My Grading program is not working correctly

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am just trying to get this simple grading program to work. I want to be able to choose from say 0-59 those and any number in between like 30, 45.8, 20.3 and so on using a switch statement. When I run it though I get errors and the output is not even showing up. I am new to c++ and I am kind of struggling.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int grade;
    cout << "Enter grade for programing class: " << flush;
    cin >> grade;


    switch (grade) {
    case 0 <= 59:
        cout << "You recived a F!" << endl;
        break;
    case 60 >= 69:
        cout << "You recived a D!" << endl;
        break;
    case 70-79:
        cout << "You recived a C!" << endl;
        break;
    case 80-89:
        cout << "You recived a B" << endl;
        break;
    case 90<=100:
        cout << "You  recived an A!" << endl;
        break;
    default:
        cout << "Please enter a real number!" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A `case` has to be a specific *value*, not a condition.

Comment: replace your switch/case with `if`s,

Comment: A `switch` statement won't work here. Use `if (grade <= 59) ... else if (grade <= 69) ...` etc. This is very common; it's known as an "if else-if ladder".

Comment: "any number in between like 30, 45.8, 20.3" - if you want to handle non-integer numbers then you should probably not be reading the input into a `int`. That will truncate any number to its integer part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use `case` in this way, instead you'd use `if` and `else`

```
if (0 <= grade && grade < 59)
else if (59 <= grade && grade < 69)
... etc
```

The `case` statement will only work with exact value matches